# Tomcat creates a jsessionid cookie when session timeouts

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, cookies

Can someone help me in pulling out this issue,
When the JSESSIONID gets expired in apache tomcat (after 30 min (or)  value) a new one is getting created automatically, why does this happen ? ,Are there any changes that i can make in the server configuration file ?

Any help is appreciated.

Update: After a little work out i came to know that "Threads are getting renewed because of the memory leak", In order to avoid a memory leak Tomcat is renewing a new thread after one gets expired by creating a random JSESSIONID

Comment: Every time whenever a new request comes to tomcat, it creates a new session for the user. So a new `JSESSIONID` cookie will be created for every new user request. Further requests will carry with that cookie to identify user. Why don't you want that? If you need stateless approach you need to change your code I think.

Comment: you are correct, but in my case without making any request by the user a new JSESSIONID is getting created (i have seen it in tomcat admin console)

Comment: Users cookie can not change without request. You have to do it by request. It would be better to check the network interaction in developer console at the browser.

Answer (score 0):

This is the normal behavior. After 30 minutes of inactivity, session is expired and removed.
You can tweak it in `web.xml`

```
<session-config>
  <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, when session expires it should remove it right, but in my case it is getting removed and a new JSESSIONID is getting created automatically (i have seen it in tomcat admin console)

Comment: That does not normally happen. New sessions are created only upon request AFAIK. Are you sure a new request is not issued on the webapp? Maybe some ajax doing periodic requests?(wild guess)